# Jade code block format

Tags: node.js, pug

While defining a code block in Jade, I am not sure whether the dash `-` in front of code is really required.

For example, I see the below code works (from http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#if):

```
if name == "Bob"
  h1 Hello Bob
else
  h1 My name is #{name}
```

This also works:

```
- if (name == "Bob")
    h1 Hello Bob
- else
    h1 My name is #{name}
```

In the second `if` parentheses are needed. I prefer first, but wanted to make sure both are correct. Jade [official docs](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/jade.md#code) shows everything in second form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can find on the [Jade reference page](http://jade-lang.com/reference/) in the "conditionals" section, you can use both as it says :

> Jade's first-class conditional syntax allows for optional parenthesis, and you may now omit the leading - otherwise it's identical, still just regular javascript